# How do I make a method call after a certain time?

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on this game for my girlfriend and I've been stuck on the same problem for a few days now. Basically, I want her to be able to press the *Gather Wood* button 5 times then, right after she presses it the fifth time, the *Create Fire* button should pop up.

1. The problem is that no matter which way I attempt to program the
   method to show up on the fifth button press it just doesn't show up.
2. I would appreciate any coding tips or anything y'all think I can do
   to clean up my current code.

   ```
   private static JPanel panel;
   private static int woodCounter;
   private static int leafCounter;
   private static JFrame frame;
   ```
3. This is the gather wood button

   ```
   public static int gatherWood() {
   woodCounter = 0;

   JButton wood = new JButton("Gather Wood");

   wood.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           System.out.println("Gathering Wood");
           woodCounter++;
           woodCounter++;
           System.out.println(woodCounter);
       }
   });

   wood.setVisible(true);
   panel.add(wood, new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

   return woodCounter;
   }
   ```
4. This is the create fire button

   ```
   public static void createFire() {
   JButton fire = new JButton("Create Fire");

   fire.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 

       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           System.out.println("Creating a fire.");

           woodCounter = woodCounter - 10;
       }
   });

   fire.setVisible(true);
   panel.add(fire, new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
   }
   ```
5. I do not know the panel size, and I don't know how to find that out. The panel is added to a `JFrame` in the `main` procedure.
6. The `gatherWood()` and `createFire()` functions are both called in main statically. Am I supposed to use `run()` to call the methods?

Comment: I remember this question from yesterday :D

Comment: I'm sorry for reposting, I just really need help on it.

Comment: Please don't post your question twice, especially after only a day. Additionally, when your reputation is high enough, you can add a bounty to attract attention to it.

Comment: So basically when you collect wood, you want the create fire button to show? In the action performed for the wood gather have you thought about adding something like `if( woodCounter >= 10){ createFire()}`, obviously it would only work the first time, as it might keep adding new buttons, but its a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should create these two buttons ("Gathering Wood" , "Create Fire"), but make second button invisible so :

```java
fire.setVisible(false);
```

and when your woodCounter will be equal 5, you make it visible.

If you need more explanation, I can show, how you can make it.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That just fixed another problem I had of the program creating multiple Create Fire buttons every time I pressed the Gathering Wood button.